# Where is the recent Maven repository for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven

Maven Central's Eclipse jar files seem to be largely frozen around 2007-2009 (Versions 3.3, in general).

Is there a current (2014) Maven repository for Eclipse jars?

Comment: http://mvnrepository.com/search.html?query=eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Services/Nexus](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Services/Nexus) eclipse Wiki-Page. The repository seems to be located at https://repo.eclipse.org.

Answer (score 0):

There is no **current** Maven repository for Eclipse projects AFAIK. https://repo.eclipse.org only contains a very small subset of Eclipse artifacts.

There is an [open issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=283745) in Eclipse bugzilla.

Comment: Wow, that issue has been alive for *five* years. I am just wishing I had a repo I could point `lein` to so I could easily get my Eclipse plugin to compile simply! Shouldn't be this hard.

Answer (score 0):

Good news: some parts (`eclipse.platform`, `eclipse.jdt`, `eclipse.pde`) of the `Neon.2` release (december 2017) are now published on maven central as well (read more [here](https://objectteams.wordpress.com/2017/01/09/eclipse-neon-2-is-on-maven-central/)).

- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/platform/
- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jdt/
- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/pde/

The poms are user friendly (simple version numbers, standard maven metadata for dependencies, source artifacts, 3rd party dependencies...) so it is now easy to use the libs in your project. Have a look at this [simple example](http://jmini.github.io/blog/2017/2017-01-10_use-eclipse-jdt-in-java-app.html) to use the Eclipse java formatter in a simple java application.